# Docker Postgresql ERROR HINT: The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory postgresql rhel

Tags: postgresql, docker, rhel7

I have a docker compose file where i am launching PostgreSQL with shared volume. But i am continuously getting the bellow ERROR.

```
2018-10-11 14:57:01.757 GMT [81] LOG:  skipping missing configuration 
file "/postgresql/data/postgresql.auto.conf"
| 2018-10-11 14:57:01.768 GMT [81] FATAL:  data directory "/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
| 2018-10-11 14:57:01.768 GMT [81] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
```

My docker compose file as below

```
addb:
image : postgres
networks:
  - private
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
volumes:
  - /mnt/shared/app_data/db/postgres/data_db:/postgresql/data
depends_on:
  - sol-server
```

I am using RHEL 7.5 and Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7. Any Idea how i can resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should mount your volume with the database in `/var/lib/postgresql/data`
instead of `/postgresql/data` or give a enviroment `PGDATA=/postgresql/data`